# $q.all - access individual promise result?

Tags: angularjs, promise, angular-promise, q

I'm a bit new to $q angular promises. Here is my code structure:

```
$q.all(promises).then(function(results) {
    results.forEach(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        console.log(status);
    });
    $scope.saveDocumentCaseState();
}, function errorCallBack(response) {
    console.log('error while mass update case entries');
    console.log(response);
    $scope.submitToWsSuccessful = 2;
});
```

Is there a possibility to access the result of each promise **when** it has been executed before the next one?

Comment: Simple answer: no. Note that the whole point of $q.all is to execute them in parallel, not one after the other.

Comment: @JBNizet hmm. Is there something else from $q I can use which will execute promise after promise and where I can see the result of each promise in order to execute some other code?

Comment: promise.then() does exactly that.

Comment: @JBNizet hmm. but then I have a small problem. I have one function which needs to execute only when all promises are fulfilled and on the other hand I need to be able to execute code after each promise is finished and before another one is started. I can't really find an answer to this with only promise.then()

Comment: Well, use all for the first case, and then() for the second one. Or simply  execute the terminal function in the last then().

Comment: Can you please provide a skeleton for such solution? As I mentioned I am very new to promises (and life).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154823/discussion-between-deniss-m-and-jb-nizet).

Comment: @JBNizet can you please assist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So assuming that you receive an array with an arbitrary number of promises from an angular factory called `promiseFactory`:

```
var promises = promiseFactory.getPromises(); // Returns an array of promises

promises.forEach(function(p){
  p.then(promiseSuccess, promiseError);

  function promiseSuccess(){
    // Do something when promise succeeds
  }

  function promiseError(){
    // Do something when promise errors
  }
});

$q.all(promises).then(allSuccess, allError);

function allSuccess(){
  // All calls executed successfully
}

function allError(){
  // At least one of the calls failed
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your effort. What if there is an array of promises: `promiseArray` how will the structure look then?

Comment: Do you want to execute the array of promises in the order that they are added to the array?

Comment: that is not relevant I think, the relevant part is that I can do something after each individual promise executed and do something when all of them executed.

Comment: Oh okay, in that case I would use `$q.all()`! I misunderstood sorry, I will update my answer.

Comment: Thanks for the updated answer. In my case there is one thing which is very important. The amount of promises is not fixed. It is dynamic. So hence the promises array used. I am not sure if I have 3 or 4 or 23 promises. :(

Comment: Okay, another curve ball :) Another question then... since it's dynamic, does that mean that the call to `then()` is exactly the same for each promise?

Comment: Well in theory yes, but in practice it could be that no. But let's make it simple for now and let it be yes. There will be a certain function that will be called after each promise succeeds and then a certain function when all promises succeed.

Comment: Yess! That's exactly what I want. Only thing is my `promises` array is an array of promises where I previously pushed my `http.post promises`. Is that ok also?

Comment: Yeah, should be absolutely fine, as long as everything in the array is a promise and it can execute the `then()` method against it.